# How can I trace my irrigation system without any sprinkler heads?

Tags: water, irrigation

I just bought a home in Arizona that came with an irrigation system in the backyard. There are no sprinkler heads so I have no clue where the lines are. How can I get info on where to plant based on the system?

Comment: if the pipes are steel or copper you can use a metal detector

Comment: You could add a radioactive gas or liquid to the pipes, let it diffuse, and then find the pipes with a Geiger counter. *(Note: Do not do this.)*